# How to get Snapchat user.display_name, bitmoji_avatar, and external_id into my php page using snapchat login kit API

Tags: php, snapchat

I am using Snapchat login kit for the web, I successfully integrated using their documentation and after authentication, it redirects to my desired PHP page, in this page, I am getting two types of variables

1. `token_type`
2. `access_token`

Now I need to get `display_name`, `bitmoji_avatar`, and `external_id`, how can I get this in my PHP page,
By the way, I searched  Snapchat demo documentation but cannot find one that can be used in my PHP page.

The following code is used to integrate the Snapchat Login kit into my project

```
<script>
  window.snapKitInit = function () {
    var loginButtonIconId = "my-login-button-target";
    // Mount Login Button
    snap.loginkit.mountButton(loginButtonIconId, {
      clientId: "my_client_id",
     redirectURI: "https://Snapreport.org/Redirect.php",
      scopeList: [
        "user.display_name",
        "user.bitmoji.avatar",
        "user.external_id",
      ],
      handleResponseCallback: function () {
        snap.loginkit.fetchUserInfo().then(
          function (result) {
            console.log("User info:", result.data.me);
            document.getElementById("display_name").innerHTML =
              result.data.me.displayName;
            document.getElementById("bitmoji").src =
              result.data.me.bitmoji.avatar;
            document.getElementById("external_id").src =
              result.data.me.externalId;
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log(err); // Error
          }
        );
      },
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js,
      sjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/login.js";
    sjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, sjs);
  })(document, "script", "loginkit-sdk");
</script>
```

and after redirection, I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: Where are you defining the redirectURL I dont see anywhere on the dev portal to add it and I Just get invalid redirect every time

Answer (score 0):

i have done it the following way to get some informations about the user...

```
const response = await axios.post("https://kit.snapchat.com/v1/me", {
            "query": "{me{displayName bitmoji{avatar} externalId}}"
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the username?